# Fail to Understand Java Two's Complement

Tags: java, int, twos-complement

I have this code:

```
package com.company;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {

    private final static int broadcast = 0xffffffff;    //4294967295, or 255.255.255.255
    private final static int firstClassE = 0xf0000000;  //4026531840, or 240.0.0.0

    public static int GetIntInetAddress(InetAddress toConvert)
    {
        final byte[] addr = toConvert.getAddress();

        final int ipAddr =
                ((addr[0] & 0xFF) << (3 * 8)) +
                        ((addr[1] & 0xFF) << (2 * 8)) +
                        ((addr[2] & 0xFF) << (1 * 8)) +
                        (addr[3] & 0xFF);

        return ipAddr;
    }

    public static Boolean IsClassEAddress(InetAddress address)
    {
        int curAddr = GetIntInetAddress(address);
        Boolean test1 = curAddr >= firstClassE;
        Boolean test2 = curAddr < broadcast;
        System.out.println(String.format("\ncurAddr: %s, firstClassE: 240.0.0.0, broadcast: 255.255.255.255", address.getHostAddress()));
        System.out.println(String.format("curAddr: %d, firstClassE: %d, broadcast: %d, curAddr >= firstClassE: %s, curAddr < broadcast: %s",
                                         curAddr, firstClassE, broadcast, test1 ? "true" : "false", test2 ? "true" : "false"));
        return (test1 && test2) ? true : false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        if (IsClassEAddress(InetAddress.getByName("1.0.0.0")))
        {
            // Raise a flag
            System.out.println("Class E IP address detected.");
        }
        if (IsClassEAddress(InetAddress.getByName("250.0.0.0")))
        {
            // Raise a flag
            System.out.println("Class E IP address detected.");
        }
        if (IsClassEAddress(InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.255")))
        {
            // Raise a flag
            System.out.println("Class E IP address detected.");
        }
        if (IsClassEAddress(InetAddress.getByName("240.0.0.0")))
        {
            // Raise a flag
            System.out.println("Class E IP address detected.");
        }
        if (IsClassEAddress(InetAddress.getByName("240.0.0.1")))
        {
            // Raise a flag
            System.out.println("Class E IP address detected.");
        }
        if (IsClassEAddress(InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255")))
        {
            // Raise a flag
            System.out.println("Class E IP address detected.");
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
curAddr: 1.0.0.0, firstClassE: 240.0.0.0, broadcast: 255.255.255.255
curAddr: 16777216, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1, curAddr >= firstClassE: true, curAddr < broadcast: false

curAddr: 250.0.0.0, firstClassE: 240.0.0.0, broadcast: 255.255.255.255
curAddr: -100663296, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1, curAddr >= firstClassE: true, curAddr < broadcast: true
Class E IP address detected.

curAddr: 239.255.255.255, firstClassE: 240.0.0.0, broadcast: 255.255.255.255
curAddr: -268435457, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1, curAddr >= firstClassE: false, curAddr < broadcast: true

curAddr: 240.0.0.0, firstClassE: 240.0.0.0, broadcast: 255.255.255.255
curAddr: -268435456, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1, curAddr >= firstClassE: true, curAddr < broadcast: true
Class E IP address detected.

curAddr: 240.0.0.1, firstClassE: 240.0.0.0, broadcast: 255.255.255.255
curAddr: -268435455, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1, curAddr >= firstClassE: true, curAddr < broadcast: true
Class E IP address detected.

curAddr: 255.255.255.255, firstClassE: 240.0.0.0, broadcast: 255.255.255.255
curAddr: -1, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1, curAddr >= firstClassE: true, curAddr < broadcast: false
```

What I am not understanding is why the numbers and comparisons are not what I expect them to be, yet the code produces the results I want.  I gather it's the whole two's complement thing, which I just don't "get" for some reason. Mechanically, I know it (two's complement) is flipping bits and adding 1 but what I don't get is, why are my comparisons working properly if some of the numbers are inverted?

For example, in the first check for IP 1.0.0.0, the int value 16777216 is checked to see if it's smaller than the int value for 255.255.255.255, which is -1.  The result is false, but the broadcast IP, when converted to an int, is obviously larger, not smaller, than the IP for 1.0.0.0.  Likewise, the check for 1.0.0.0 being at least, or higher than, 240.0.0.0 returns true, when we know that clearly isn't the case.

I've checked the boundary cases and everything is working... I just don't understand why it is (and I wrote the code, so go figure!).  If there is a more clear method of determining if an IP fals within a range, I would like to explore that as my way must not be making sense, despite working (or does it?)

In IntelliJ, there's another strange example of this behaviour.  When I examine an address, the inspector is showing both the proper value and the negative value, as I've highlighted with red arrows in the pic below.  Using Windows calc, I put in -84 and converted to hex and received FFF...FAC. When I put in 172, I received just AC... why do I get the same hex number, just preceeded by a 1 in the most sig position?

[image: Another strange example I've seen]

**UPDATE**:

Thanks for all the patient discussion and great answers!  I think I get the mechanics of the thing, but still grappling with the subtleties of usage.  :)  Cheers!

Comment: That's a big wall of code and output. Can you not provide a tiny snippet that demonstrates your misunderstanding around two's complement?

Comment: _"the broadcast IP, when converted to an int, is obviously larger, not smaller, than the IP for 1.0.0.0"_  -- this is not at all "obvious".  `1.0.0.0` in binary is `0x01000000` and `255.255.255.255` is `0xFFFFFFFF`.  The first value represents `16777216 ` and the second value represents `-1`.  You can't change this by saying you don't "get" two's-complement.  It just is.

Comment: If you want comparisons to work right, the easiest way is to use a `long` instead of an `int`, and then everything will be positive.

Comment: `return (test1 && test2) ? true : false;` trololo

Comment: @ajb, maybe I'm old-fashioned but I would argue that if you want comparisons to work right the easiest way is to understand what you are comparing...

Comment: @JimGarrison: My confusion comes from the fact that, just looking at the numbers, `0x01000000` is a smaller number than `0xFFFFFFFF`.  Otherwise, how can `255.255.255.255` be a larger IP than `1.0.0.0`?

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` is "larger" than `0x01000000` ONLY if the comparison is unsigned.  As a Java `int` which is signed, it is smaller.

Comment: @JimGarrison: If you wouldn't mind having a peek at my comment below in response to 0xbe5077ed's answer, how would I best write these comparisons?  I'm sorely tempted to just shut my eyes, forget the whole mess and just deal with longs instead, but surely using ints for this must be valid too, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, you want `IsClassEAddress(InetAddress address)` to return true if the address is between `240.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.254` inclusive. This takes 2 lines of code:

```
public static Boolean IsClassEAddress(InetAddress address)
{
    int curAddr = GetIntInetAddress(address);
    return ((curAddr & 0xF0000000) == 0xF0000000) && (curAddr != 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

Comment: That is clean.  My func shown above was long-winded but I had expanded it so I could examine each test's result.  Your test however, makes much more sense. I did have one question though, posed above.  Suppose my range crossed the highest +value -> lowest -value boundary.  If I run a number that should be within that range through the above, it fails.  Would that be expected?

Comment: For example, suppose I wanted to check if a number fell into the range `0x7fffffff` through `0xa0000000` with a sample number `0x90000000`. Running that through the first part of the above test, I have `0x90000000 & 0x7fffffff = 0x10000000`.

Comment: It seems to fall apart for other ranges too.  Suppose I have 0x30000000 as the lower bound; 0x40000000 & 0x30000000 = 0. 0x500000 & 0x30000000 = 0x10000000.

Comment: This type of masking works only if the range boundaries are expressed in binary as some number of 1 bits followed by all zero bits, as is the case for netmasks.  For arbitrary ranges it cannot be made to work with just masking.  IF you want to use arbitrary ranges, put your unsigned masked bytes into a `long`.

Comment: Oh okay, so I'd need 1's right through the most significant bit for this kind of simple masking to work properly, is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

In a 32-bit two's complement number, the non-negative integers are `0x00000000` - `0x7fffffff` and these convert from hex to deciminal in the ordinary way.

The *lowest* (*ie* most negative) number is represented in the machine as `0x80000000` (*ie* the highest-order bit and no other bit is set). What this bit being set really means is add the positive integer indicated by the 31 lower-order bits to the number `-(0x80000000)`.

**Exercise**: *What is the number -84 in 32-bit two's complement?* Since it is negative, we have to set the high-order bit. So we start with `-(0x80000000) = -2147483648`. Now you can solve algebraically what the other 31 bits need to be:

```
-2147483648 + x = -84
=> x = 2147483648 - 84
=> x = 2147483564
=> x = 0x7fffffac
```

And it should be obvious that if you take `0x80000000 | 0x7fffffac`, you get `0xffffffac`.

It should also be obvious that `0x7fffffac = (0x7f000000 + 0xff0000 + 0xff00 + 0xac)` and the expression in parentheses is equivalent to `(2130706432 + 16711680 + 65280 + 172)`. The fact that the lower-order byte is equivalent to decimal `172` is meaningless without considering the other 3 bytes.

**Your Comparisons**

Now you mention that your comparisons are "not what you expect them to be". I don't know what you expect them to be since you haven't explained, but my guess is you want a `true` return value for IP addresses in the range `[240.0.0.0 .. 255.255.255.255)` non-inclusive of the right-hand side of the range. This means IP addresses in the range `[0xf0000000 .. 0xffffffff)` non-inclusive.

If those are 32-bit two's complement integers, this is the range `[-268435456, -1)`, so any expression of the form `(0xf0000000 <= ip_addr && ip_addr < 0xffffffff)` will give you the correct result.

Since your function returns a more convoluted version of the above expression, it gives the correct result.

By the way, are you familiar with the `boolean` type? Is there some reason your method needs to return a boxed primitive (*ie* `Boolean`)?

Comment: So, the numbers go from 0 to most positive to most negative to -1? As in, `0,1,2..127,-128,-127..-1`?  The computer thinks -128 comes immediately after +127 and -1 is a perfectly reasonable interpretation of the biggest number in the sequence (ie: the number with all bits set)?  No wonder computers are so screwy, they can't even count in a straight line!  LOL TBC...

Comment: Cont'd.  So, what is the correct way to write these comparisons?  If I set first to be 120, last to be -120, curr to be 125.  The checks would exclude that since first (120) <= curr (125) = true and curr (125) < last (-120) = false.  But, according to the sequence I wrote above, it should be included in the range, yes?

Comment: @Jon, you are correct that if you do `byte b = Byte.MAX_VALUE; ++b;` then the expression `Byte.MIN_VALUE == b` will be `true`. Same for shorts, ints, longs. However, I think your second comment is overcomplicating things. My answer explains to you that your comparisons work because the IP address range you care about is a contiguous range of negative numbers. If you care about an IP address range in which one end is `w.x.y.z` with `128 <= w` and the other end is `a.b.c.d` with `a < 128` then you may have two non-contiguous ranges that require a more careful approach.

Comment: @Jon, by the way if you feel your question has been answered, feel free to accept one of the proffered answers.

Comment: I was thinking more of the case where I would be crossing the `0x7fffff` -> `0x80000000` boundary.  Forgetting IPs for a moment, suppose I wanted to check if a number fell into the range `0x7fffffff` through `0xa0000000` with a sample number `0x90000000`.  Running that through the first part of @jimgarrison 's proposal below, I have `0x90000000 & 0x7fffffff = 0x10000000`.  The test fails. Would I necessarily have to split the comparison into two tests then, one from the lowest + boundary to the highest + value and another test for the smallest - value to the highest - boundary?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can make sure unsigned 32-bit integers are compared correctly:

1)  Use [`Integer.compareUnsigned`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareUnsigned-int-int-), which was added in Java 8.

2)  Use a `long` instead of an `int`.  If the value is constructed properly, the results will be positive integers in the range 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1, which can then be compared with no problem.  You have to be careful about the order in which casting and bitwise operations take place, so that things don't sign extend.  This works:

```
    final long ipAddr =
            (((long)addr[0] & 0xFF) << (3 * 8)) +
            (((long)addr[1] & 0xFF) << (2 * 8)) +
            (((long)addr[2] & 0xFF) << (1 * 8)) +
            ((long)addr[3] & 0xFF);
```

When each `byte` is cast to a `long`, it will sign extend, but the `& 0xFF` zeroes any 1 bits that were added with sign extension.

3)  Write a `compare` method, or `lessThan` or `lessThanOrEqual` or whatever you need, that accounts for the signs.  A method like this would have to have special cases for when the arguments have different signs.  E.g.:

```
static int compareUnsigned(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= 0 && y < 0) {
        return -1;        // y is actually greater than x if unsigned
    }
    else if (x < 0 && y >= 0) {
        return 1;         // x is greater than y if unsigned
    } else {
        return Integer.compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

or, more compactly,

```
static int compareUnsigned(int x, int y) {
    if (((x ^ y) & 0x80000000) != 0) {  // see if x and y have different signs
        return (x < 0) ? 1 : -1;     
    } else {
        return Integer.compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Actually, this is how it's done in the Java 8 source:

```
static int compareUnsigned(int x, int y) {
    return Integer.compare(x + Integer.MIN_VALUE, y + Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}
```

which I didn't think of at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this is an issue with two's complement, I can only advise you to read up on it and finally get it - it will bite you again and again in various integer overflow problems (It's even used in some of the core Java libraries).

The issue itself is that in Java Integer holds numbers from -(2^31) to (2^31)-1. The value of 255*255*255*255 is 2^32 - 1. It's *not representable* as a signed int. Hence when you convert the IP to a *signed* int you don't get a sensible (to you) value. If you want to compare IPs with the built in 'less than' use a primitive where an IP will actually fit - like a `long`.

Same thing happening in the second part. A signed `byte` holds values from -128 to 127. You are putting 255 there. Why are you expecting a sane result? Now if you use unsigned arithmetic where byte holds 0..255, it all works fine.